# Put media filter in place of electronic air filter

Tags: hvac, air-filter

I have a trion iaq 1400 electronic air filter in my house. I decided to take the filters out and replace them with a 5 inch media filter. My problem is that there is a small space between the filter and the door. Any suggestions about how to fill that space? Thank you

Comment: it is unclear what this means ... `small space between the filter and the door` ............... a picture would help

Comment: I mean that the "door" that opens to pull out the electronic filters. The electronic filters came up pretty flush to this door, but the Media filter is a little short. I am using a 16x25x5, so the 25 dimension doesn't quite reach. But for now I just folded up some cardboard and taped it to the door so that it sort of closed that gap.

Comment: why do you have to close the gap between the filter edge and the door? ..... is it causing airflow problems?